# Kill secondary task of a given process

Tags: python, powershell, batch-file, process

I'm trying to kill a secondary task of a process using powershell, batch, python...anything I can save as script and run it remotely. TaskManager picture as following:

[image: TaskManager]

I'd like to kill the one with longer title leaving the "SAP Logon 740" open. Every task of the tree have the same PID, so I can't just kill the process.

I guess this is posible, because  I can do it manually going to Task MAnager, expanding the process and ending that specific task but everything I've found consist in killing the process, which isn't possible in my case.

I've so far tried with tasklist/taskkill, powershell (Get-Process, Get-Object Win32_Process...) but I haven't been able to find how to.

Here you have the output of TaskList (Status=Running)

[image: Output]

Only one of the task (the one which is front) is showing there.

Comment: [Stop-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/stop-process?view=powershell-6#syntax)

Comment: Your image is showing Task Manager's grouping of individual tasks under their running parent app, this does not mean that they're sharing the same process identifier. Your GUI screenshot has no reason to be part of this question, what would be more useful to us would be the representative formatted output from `TaskList /V /Fi "Status Eq Running"`.

Comment: added in the question

Comment: You'll notice that the one you've not shown does not have a `PID` of `2612`, as I've already stated. Now open a Command Prompt window, enter `TaskKill /?` and read the usage information. You'll notice that you can filter its selections using information such as its Image Name and Window Title!

Comment: If I try to use `Taskkill /F /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq ABAP*"`it closes both windows, the one with windowtitle ABAP* and the one with SAP LOGON 740.

Comment: You have cropped the `PID` column from the _TaskManager picture_.  Note that items _with_ `PID` show another right-click menu than items _without_ `PID` (and it's the case). I don't know how to kill those subtask(s) programmatically. Even the `Terminate` method of the `Win32_Process` class   terminates a process and all of its threads. I cannot see a method to terminate a particular  thread…

Answer (score 0):

As you have used the [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) tag, and even ran your `tasklist` command using `powerhell.exe`, I have decided to provide an examples using it.

If your criteria is to stop the process named **`saplogon`** with the longest window title string:

```
GPs saplogon|Sort{$_.mainWindowTitle.Length}|Select -L 1|SpPs -Wh
```

If your criteria is to stop all processes named **`saplogon`** except for the one with the shortest window title string:

```
GPs saplogon|Sort{$_.mainWindowTitle.Length}|Select -Skip 1|SpPs -Wh`
```

If you're happy with the output, you can remove  **`-Wh`**, *(`-WhatIf`)*, to actually perform the task. If needed you could even replace that with the  **`-F`**, *(`-Force`)* option, *if necessary*.

Comment: Please use full cmdlets in your answer(s) instead of aliases. Using cmdlets makes the code more clear and consistent when shared with other people. (Yes, I know that using alias in an interactive console is useful to speed up but makes the code less clear. Moreover, some aliases are not too intuitive and it can be difficult to remember all of them… if one isn't a linux geek [grin]…)

Comment: I tried before executing the whole command to only list what's getting (whitout the select and the SpPs), and only one line appear.

Even so I gave a try to both. With the first one (Kill the one with longer title) the result was to close both. With the second nothing happens (I guess this is because the Skip 1, it skips the only existin line).

Comment: @iVrLx, I was not sure that you tried it, because I'm not a mind reader and you were not respectful enough to provide a [mcve] of your code as mentioned in the guidelines for good questions. Next  time, you have an issue, be sure not to waste other members time and effort, by taking the [tour] and reading [ask] before posting.